# ffplay command to play 3 audio track togerter

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have `.ts` file with 3 Audio tracks and 1 Video track.
I know how to mix 3 audio tracks with FFmpeg. But I want to use ffplay to play it only. Not to encode.

```
 ffplay -af "[0:1][0:2][0:3]amerge=inputs=3[aout]" -map "    [aout]" -ac 2 -i "input.ts"
```

But it's got an error.

> Failed to set value '[aout]' for option 'map': Option not found

Does FFmpeg command can use with ffplay or it's have any different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=in.ts[out0];amovie=in.ts:s='a\:0'+'a\:1'+'a\:2',amerge=3[out1]"
```

Comment: It's output only audio I needed video on stream 0 too.
Here's my file looks like
TS
-Video 0
-Audio 0
-Audio 1
-Audio 2